# Pheanstalk in Laravel, Everything ends up as an unhandled response?

Tags: php, laravel, pheanstalk

Ive installed the Pheanstalk bundle for Laravel (https://github.com/mikelbring/Pheanstalk)
I am now following the basic example code to try and pass a job to the queue and retrieve it back again.

This is my code:

```
Route::get('queue', function()
{

Pheanstalk::useTube('testtube')->put("job payload goes here\n");

$pheanstalk = Pheanstalk::connection();

$job = $pheanstalk
  ->watch('testtube')
  ->ignore('default')
  ->reserve();

echo $job->getData();

$pheanstalk->delete($job);
});
```

Yet when i run it, i get an 'Unhandled Response' error, like nothing has been returned.

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Unhandled response: 
Location:

C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\bundles\pheanstalk\pheanstalk\classes\Pheanstalk\Command\PutCommand.php on line 108
Stack Trace:

 #0 C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\bundles\pheanstalk\pheanstalk\classes\Pheanstalk\Connection.php(121): Pheanstalk_Command_PutCommand->parseResponse('', NULL)
#1 C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\bundles\pheanstalk\pheanstalk\classes\Pheanstalk.php(511): Pheanstalk_Connection->dispatchCommand(Object(Pheanstalk_Command_PutCommand))
#2 C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\bundles\pheanstalk\pheanstalk\classes\Pheanstalk.php(273): Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk->_dispatch(Object(Pheanstalk_Command_PutCommand))
#3 C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\application\routes.php(45): Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk->put('job payload goe...')
#4 [internal function]: Laravel\Bundle::{closure}()
#5 C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\laravel\routing\route.php(163): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\laravel\routing\route.php(124): Laravel\Routing\Route->response()
#7 C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\laravel\laravel.php(167): Laravel\Routing\Route->call()
#8 C:\wamp\www\adam\phire\public\index.php(34): require('C:\wamp\www\ada...')
#9 {main}
```

Is anyone familiar with Pheanstalk and can provide some assistance?

Thanks
Adam.

Comment: Unfortunately the only option I see is to file a bug to the "Pheanstalk for Laravel" bundle maintainer https://github.com/mikelbring/Pheanstalk/issues, or make a pull request if you find a fix :-/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/blob/master/classes/Pheanstalk/Command/PutCommand.php#L103) is where that exception gets raised. Seems like your beanstalkd is returning something that pheanstalk doesn't understand. Are you sure you're connecting to a working beanstalkd implementation?

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the Pheanstalk Laravel bundle. Have you tried testing with a regular Pheanstalk using the same connection details?